# How to get rid of initial value of Variable in RxSwift

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I have been working on RxSwift, I am using a `Variable` in RxSwift which is hooked(bind to) to `UICollectionView`. Now knowing that `Variable` extends from `Behavior Subjects` I had to create a `Variable` with some dummy initial value.

```
 var myArray = Variable<[MyDataModel]>([MyDataModel(data: "{:}")])
```

`MyDataModel` is a struct that takes `json` as a init parameter.(As MyModel has nothing to with the question that follows am not posting the structure of it here)

Now, when I hook it to collectionView, I know that I should ignore the first signal emitted so I use `skip(1)`

```
myArray.asObservable().skip(1).bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "test", cellType: MyCollectionViewCell.self){
        //cell implementation    
})
```

Though above code works, it solves the problem partially. Though the first change in the `value` of `myArray` is ignored, but when I append the actually data to `myArray` later using

```
myArray.value.append(someNewData)
```

it emits the notification and unfortunately this time `myArray.value` has two values (dummy one I added while initializing and one that actually triggered `onNext`)

So as a work around, what I do is before blindly appending data to `myArray.value` I check if it has dummy object I added, if yes I remove it and add the actual object.

Though work around works, makes my code looks very ugly and non Rx in a way. I believe there must be a proper way to deal with it as it is a very fundamental problem working with `Variable`.

I would really appreciate your thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, *Variable* is deprecated in RxSwift 4.x in favor of *BehaviorRelay*.

But for your purpose, *PublishSubject* or *BehaviorSubject* (if you need to cache the latest value) should suffice.

Comment: I am using RxSwift 4.0 and I dont see any deprecation warning for Variable, I checked the source code as well no deprecation added. Are you sure Variable is deprecated in RxSwift4 ? Second I cant use Publush,Behaviour subjects because both can get terminated by error or completed event. But conceptually its a variable bound to collectionView data source which cant end with error or have completed state.I know I can use asDriver() with Publish/Behavior but thought variable is intended for that reason itself

Comment: See the last bullet in https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/releases/tag/4.0.0-rc.0

Comment: True, I see that. I need to confirm from kzaher about the same I guess :(

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about Variable deprecation. +1

Comment: Regarding errors/completion - it depends on how you put data into the subject, if you only call *.onNext()* then you are safe. If it is a succession of service calls, I would rather put requests into a subject of observables (sic) and bind *.switchLatestDelayError()* to the UI.

Comment: I am using RxSwift4 yet I cant access BehaviorRelay, which Rxversion are you on?? BTW I raised a issue https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1501

Comment: 4.0.0; Here it is - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/Traits/BehaviorRelay.swift

Comment: I know its a different question and if you want Ill post a new question on this, but looks like BehaviorRelay's value is immutable, in case of Variable I would use variable.value.append(newItem) now how can I achieve the same with  BehaviorRelay

Comment: Lemme post a new question wait